# Internal error in Firestore (0.6.6-dev) when trying to update document

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

The following error is giving me a hard time. I'm trying to update a single field in a document stored in my Firestore project.

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error in Firestore (0.6.6-dev).
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzejs.run(Unknown Source)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5365)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot perform this operation because there is no current transaction.
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.throwIfNoTransaction(SQLiteSession.java:926)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.endTransaction(SQLiteSession.java:398)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.endTransaction(SQLiteDatabase.java:524)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzefi.zzb(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzedu.zzcao(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzedu.start(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeca.zza(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzecc.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:390)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:153)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:267)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzejp$zza.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Here is my code:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

if(user == null){
    Log.e(LOGTAG, "Could not upload because user is not logged in.");
    return;
}

FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
DocumentReference userRef = db.collection("users").document(user.getUid());

TextInputEditText textview = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_foo);
String enteredText = textview.getText().toString(); //implements CharSequence, thus toString() gives the correct string
userRef.update("field_foo", enteredText)
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                Log.i(LOGTAG, "Text successfully updated!");
            }
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Error updating text", e);
            }
        });
```

The error occurs everytime the method is executed. Imho, the "internal error" phrase might indicate that this is indeed a problem coming with the early beta status of the Firestore database. However, this is my first android app and I'm also new to Firebase. Any qualified valuation, any idea for a solution or any pointer?

Comment: Dan this does not seem to be the fault of anything you are doing.  Can you try clearing your app's data and then trying again?

Comment: I just realized - does the document you're trying to update exist yet?  If not could you try using a set() call instead?  In either case I would not expect an internal assertion but I want to narrow down the cause.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to @hatboysam, it works now.
The solution is as simple as can be:

**Clear the data in the application manager on the device.**

Then run the app again.

Comment: For anyone else reading this, it seems like the SQLite database got corrupted somehow.  If anyone else can reproduce this please reach out to me.

Comment: Clearing the data in the application manager is not a viable option for real clients. How do we fix this programmatically?

Comment: The SQLite can be corrupted after try to do some operations that needs 100% internet, such as transactions. If you try to do a transaction without internet, the application will keep in a loop forever. together with the "request" on the database. Keep control of it to avoid this problems

Comment: Hey @SamStern, I encounted this exception so much times. I add Firestore to app, feature related to Firestore is just get/set on 2 documents of uuid in 2 collections (user & userdata) , and add only one Realtime listener. Then connect to internet via both data & wifi, open app -> leave it to background -> wait for 10 - 15 minutes -> disconnect wifi => Exception occur

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when your are initializing the Firestore object multiple times in many processes. So instead of declaring it again and again, declare it globally and use accordingly..

Comment: If you try to use Firestore from multiple processes, it should give you an error (saying "Failed to gain exclusive lock to the Firestore client's offline persistence. This generally means you are using Firestore from multiple processes in your app ...").  If you're seeing something different, can you please let me know (and ideally provide sample code)?