# Internal error when listening to changes on Firestore data + Permission Denied when making update to Firestore data

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46676480/6097322) and **resolved the below internal error** I was getting when the app after being deployed makes a Firebase Firestore get call.

```
com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: INTERNAL: An internal error occurred.
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzevs.zzf(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzenb.zza(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeoa.zza(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzenf.zza(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzett.zza(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzett.zza(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzetu.zzb(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeup.zzcg(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeth.zzcg(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzevi.zzch(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfmg.zzch(Unknown Source)
      at io.grpc.internal.zzac.zzdep(Unknown Source)
      at io.grpc.internal.zzaq.run(Unknown Source)
      at io.grpc.internal.zzeo.run(Unknown Source)
      at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:269)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeuu$zza.run(Unknown Source)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
   Caused by: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfok: INTERNAL: An internal error occurred.
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfof.zzddl(Unknown Source)
```

These are the 2 errors I am getting on another device where the app is already deployed.

The first **INTERNAL** error is thrown on adding the listeners that listen to the changes on one collection in Firestore:

```
com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: INTERNAL: An internal error occurred.
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzevs.zzf(Unknown Source:22)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzenb.zza(Unknown Source:30)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeoa.zza(Unknown Source:126)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzenf.zza(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzett.zza(Unknown Source:92)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzett.zza(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzetu.zzb(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeup.zzcg(Unknown Source:28)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeth.zzcg(Unknown Source:50)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzevi.zzch(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfmg.zzch(Unknown Source:4)
        at io.grpc.internal.zzac.zzdep(Unknown Source:40)
        at io.grpc.internal.zzaq.run(Unknown Source:6)
        at io.grpc.internal.zzeo.run(Unknown Source:13)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeuu$zza.run(Unknown Source:7)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfok: INTERNAL: An internal error occurred.
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfof.zzddl(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzevs.zzf(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzenb.zza(Unknown Source:30) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeoa.zza(Unknown Source:126) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzenf.zza(Unknown Source:2) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzett.zza(Unknown Source:92) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzett.zza(Unknown Source:0) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzetu.zzb(Unknown Source:2) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeup.zzcg(Unknown Source:28) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeth.zzcg(Unknown Source:50) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzevi.zzch(Unknown Source:2) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfmg.zzch(Unknown Source:4) 
        at io.grpc.internal.zzac.zzdep(Unknown Source:40) 
        at io.grpc.internal.zzaq.run(Unknown Source:6) 
        at io.grpc.internal.zzeo.run(Unknown Source:13) 
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeuu$zza.run(Unknown Source:7) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

The second **PERMISSION_DENIED** is thrown when trying to add a document in a Firestore collection

```
com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzevs.zzf(Unknown Source:22)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeoa.zzc(Unknown Source:26)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeoa.zzb(Unknown Source:6)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzenf.zzb(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzett.zze(Unknown Source:73)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzett.zzb(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzetv.zzb(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzetd.zza(Unknown Source:83)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzetd.zza(Unknown Source:15)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzetd.zza(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeth.zzb(Unknown Source:53)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzevi.zza(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfmg.zza(Unknown Source:4)
        at io.grpc.internal.zzv.zza(Unknown Source:7)
        at io.grpc.internal.zzx.zza(Unknown Source:0)
        at io.grpc.internal.zzx.zza(Unknown Source:0)
        at io.grpc.internal.zzx$zza.zzc(Unknown Source:12)
        at io.grpc.internal.zzx$zza.zza(Unknown Source:0)
        at io.grpc.internal.zzad.zzdep(Unknown Source:15)
        at io.grpc.internal.zzaq.run(Unknown Source:6)
        at io.grpc.internal.zzeo.run(Unknown Source:13)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeuu$zza.run(Unknown Source:7)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfok: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfof.zzddl(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzevs.zzf(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeoa.zzc(Unknown Source:26) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeoa.zzb(Unknown Source:6) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzenf.zzb(Unknown Source:2) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzett.zze(Unknown Source:73) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzett.zzb(Unknown Source:0) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzetv.zzb(Unknown Source:2) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzetd.zza(Unknown Source:83) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzetd.zza(Unknown Source:15) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzetd.zza(Unknown Source:0) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeth.zzb(Unknown Source:53) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzevi.zza(Unknown Source:2) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfmg.zza(Unknown Source:4) 
        at io.grpc.internal.zzv.zza(Unknown Source:7) 
        at io.grpc.internal.zzx.zza(Unknown Source:0) 
        at io.grpc.internal.zzx.zza(Unknown Source:0) 
        at io.grpc.internal.zzx$zza.zzc(Unknown Source:12) 
        at io.grpc.internal.zzx$zza.zza(Unknown Source:0) 
        at io.grpc.internal.zzad.zzdep(Unknown Source:15) 
        at io.grpc.internal.zzaq.run(Unknown Source:6) 
        at io.grpc.internal.zzeo.run(Unknown Source:13) 
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeuu$zza.run(Unknown Source:7) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

As per one of the comment by @sam-stern [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46676480/6097322), there should be no problem with the code as it has been working for months now, I am not putting any code for now. But if anyone feels it is required, I am happy to provide it.

There is another comment by @Sam Stern, that says to reach out to him in case of encountering the same error. But I am not aware how to directly reach out to you, hence posting the question here.

> My question is whether **clear the app data** is the only solution to remove these exceptions or there is some proper way to make it work correctly like it had been.

Comment: What about the Firestore security rules ? Did you open the read/write rule ?

Comment: @olivejp nope have not touched them either